# source and include file errors in Vcs c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The source file "implot.h" cannot be found. and Unable to open include file.'main.h" no such file or directory.
I always get these errors even though I add the header files to the project.
Why do we get these errors? what do you think i should do?
[image]

Comment: Can you share the contents of `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Answer (score 0):

Check your head files' "Full Path" and "Relative Path" properties are correct.
You have items under the filters, but it doesn't mean they are in correct directories.

Let's look at the picture. I guess she created a new project and unzip/untar source to a new folder wherever it was.

[project folder]

- *.cpp ==> #include "source_header_files.h" // illegal

[source folder]

- *.cpp ==> #include "source_header_files.h" // legal
- source_header_files.h

Except changing the "Project Property -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include Directories" property or #include directive in implementation files, preprocessor will never find the header files.

So no matter how she added the header files, VS always never find them. They are in different folders.

My idea is making the source library or dll. That would be better.

Comment: The answer should be expanded to explain where the properties can be changed, and to what they should be changed. Maybe also mention clearly that how a filter differs from a directory